# How to stop players from seeing your game's code

Tags: security, game-development

I'm making a game in unity that you download on your computer via steam (or something). I want to have a place where you can type in questions, and if someone figures out the correct question to ask something big happens.

Now I really don't know if anyone's gonna play this game, but it would be a shame if the fun would be ruined by someone looking at the code and finding what to say. Is this possible?

I would just hardcode an if statement for what question to ask, but I've never published a game before, so I really don't know how this works. Can people actually see the code or is it just all binary? What if I put what question to ask on an online database somewhere else and then bring it in?

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, Is stack overflow the best place to ask this question since it isn't about debugging code?

Comment: Only safe way would be to have a server somewhere validating the question.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, it's impossible for the players to see your C# code, because players download a **build** of your game, which only contains the compiled version of your code.

Comment: That's not true at all. It's actually very easy to de-compile .NET code. Even more so to find strings in binaries.